# Limit the update jump in value in a column

Tags: mysql

lets say i have a column called 'balance', this is the amount of money user has, now i want to prevent a high jump in this value so the user or a hacker cannot raise this value as much as he wants, lets say the user balance now is 100, i don't want some malicious user to be able to update it to 999 at once. the raise in the balance value should be gradual , by tiers of maximum 20.

can i do this with mysql? or only with php

```
<?php

echo "for quality check;dismiss";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the combination of php and mysql.

Only mysql or Only php will not help in this case.

```
Process would be as follows:
- fetch value from database
- take value of user input
- compare it with the value of database
- if difference is <=20 then update the value other wise not
```

let me know if you need more information

Thanks
Amit

Comment: yes i tought of that, thats a good solution, i just wondered if a hacker can do it directly on the db instead of php

Comment: Yes they can if they get direct access to your db server (direct connection/login or even sql injection vulnerability in your code). You might use a trigger to check each update is allowed, but still if someone has access to your server, they could remove this check. Security is important.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write an UPDATE trigger that checks the value before updating the column. It should be something like this

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER check_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON your_table FOR EACH ROW
IF (NEW.userbalance <= OLD.userbalance+20) THEN
  SET NEW.userbalance = NEW.userbalance;
ELSE
  SET NEW.userbalance = OLD.userbalance;
END IF;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: And what will this do in the ELSE case? Seems to me it will update anyway. Should it instead signal an error or limit the new balance? (thats probably a question to @Noobit )

Comment: Nice. It does not signal anything wrong, but that was not asked for.. :)